# > operator after an = .. PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, operator-keyword

Just came by this code in Laravel Paginator.php today

```
$this->hasMore = $this->items->count() > $this->perPage;
```

I'm familiar with -> and > but not sure how this bigger than fits after an = .
this is the full function :

```
protected function setItems($items)
{
    $this->items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);

    $this->hasMore = $this->items->count() > $this->perPage;

    $this->items = $this->items->slice(0, $this->perPage);
}
```

Comment: That's a boolean evaluation, which will result in a boolean value stored in `hasMore`.

Comment: In structure identical to `$x = 5 > 3;`

Comment: The > is evaluated before the = (assignation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right side is evaluated and the result is assigned to the left. This of it this way:

```
$a = ($b > $c);
```

Where this evaluates to a boolean:

```
($b > $c)
```

Alternatively:

```
$a = ($b > $c) ? true : false;
```

Or:

```
if ($b > $c) {
    $a = true;
} else {
    $a = false;
}
```